# React typescript with react-redux component requires all passed props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

So I've just started to combine react, redux (react-redux) and typescript. But I can't seem to figure out something here, namely, why the child components inside of the *App* component require all of the props that I pass into the *App* component.

App component:

```
const App = ({contacts, user, activeUserId}: ApplicationState) => (
    <div className="App">
        <Sidebar contacts={contacts} />
        <Main user={user} activeUserId={activeUserId}/>
    </div>
);

const getContacts = ({contacts, user, activeUserId}: ApplicationState) => ({contacts, user, activeUserId});
export default connect(getContacts)(App);
```

Sidebar component:

```
const Sidebar = ({contacts}: ApplicationState) => {
    let contactsValues: Array<Contacts> = contacts && Object.values(contacts);

    return (
        <aside className="Sidebar">
            {contactsValues && contactsValues.map((contact: Contacts) => <User user={contact} key={contact.user_id}/>)}
        </aside>
    )
}
```

I don't think there's any reason to list the *Main* component here as well since its only an empty component but gives the same errors, so I will just go ahead an list the *Interfaces*:

```
export default interface Contacts {
    email: string,
    name: string,
    profile_pic: string,
    status: string,
    user_id: string
}

export default interface ApplicationState {
    contacts: Contacts,
    user: object,
    activeUserId: string | null
}
```

Actual error code: "TS2739: Type '{ contacts: Contacts; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ApplicationState': user, activeUserId"

So, both components ask to have *all* the props injected into them, even though they are not required inside the component itself. If I supply the components the everything works and I get no errors.

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my syntax or 'wiring' of the types.

Can we also get a explanation or a decent link to docs/materials that help us understand why this is happening?

If there is anything else that I should be including please let me know and I will provide!

Edit:

I've actually realized that its important to show the *Main* component too because this one also causes problems and some of the fixes you guys have suggested only fix the *Sidebar* component but not the *Main*.

Main component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Main.scss";

import ApplicationState from "../../models/ApplicationState";

const Main = ({user, activeUserId}: ApplicationState) => {
    return (
        <main className="Main">
            Main Stuff
        </main>
    )
}
```

Edit:

From what I've experimented with all of these answers I think the best solution would be to make everything in the interfaces optional, but if I do this then the *contactsValues* variable inside the *Sidebar* component throws: *TS2322: Type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Contacts[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Contacts[]'.*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your Sidebar component where you just passed the contacts and defined its type to be ApplicationState... Change Sidebar parameter as:

```
const Sidebar = (contacts: Contacts) => { 
let contactsValues: Array<Contacts> = contacts && Object.values(contacts); 
return 
 ( <aside className="Sidebar"> 
   {contactsValues && contactsValues.map((contact: Contacts) =>
   <User user={contact} key={contact.user_id}/>
   )} 
  </aside> ) }
```

Another way to resolve the error is to make interface attribute optional as:

**Update**

I think there is one more problem with the interfaces:

```
export default interface Contact {   //It's a single object, So Contact is OK
 email: string,
 name: string,
 profile_pic: string,
 status: string,
 user_id: string
}
export default interface ApplicationState {
 contacts: Contact[],   // I guess you need an array of Contacts
 user?: object, 
 activeUserId?: string 
}
```

And I think you are getting error because of wrong initialization. Change to

```
let contactsValues: Array<Contacts> = contacts ? Object.values(contacts): [] as Contact[];
```

Comment: Hello @MuhammadUmarFarooq, your first solution makes it so I can't use *destructuring* on the props object anymore and makes it so that we would have to use a lot of workarounds or more syntax.

The second solution is a partial fix, it fixes the problem inside of the *Sidebar* component but not for the *Main* component.

Comment: Ok so, something you said got my attention in the right place, namely, the initialization, that was a big part of the problem, but not only that, it was also the interface types.
Here is the answer:

1. All interface types in the *ApplicationState* must be optional since they are not required in all of the components, I still don't understand why they are all being required in all of the components simply because they are used to map the *father* component props but that seems to be how it works.

Comment: 2. *let contactsValues: Array<Contacts> | undefined = contacts && Object.values(contacts)* - this seems to be the right way to initialize the variable, why? I think it is because the value inside this variable is being created using a prop that is optional and as such might not be passed in to the component! Makes sens right? If *contacts?* is optional the it might end up being undefined inside of *Sidebar* and as such *contactsValues* should have both types.

I'm making your answer as the correct one because your answer helped me find out what was wrong.

Thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this function

```
const Sidebar = ({contacts}: ApplicationState) => {
    let contactsValues: Array<Contacts> = contacts && Object.values(contacts);

    return (
        <aside className="Sidebar">
            {contactsValues && contactsValues.map((contact: Contacts) => <User user={contact} key={contact.user_id}/>)}
        </aside>
    )
}
```

the type `{ contacts: Contacts }` is not the same type `ApplicationState`

If you want to pass just contacts to your function you must create a new type or
make `ApplicationState` like this

```
    export default interface ApplicationState {
        contacts: Contacts,
        user?: object,
        activeUserId?: string | null
    }
```

Comment: Hello @rubendamatos1985, if I try your solution the *Sidebar* will no longer throw a error but the *Main* component will still throw a error in reference to the fact that it is *not* getting the *contacts* property.
Error: *TS2741: Property 'contacts' is missing in type '{ user: object | undefined; activeUserId: string | null | undefined; }' but required in type 'ApplicationState'.*

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Applicationstate interface with this :

```
 export default interface ApplicationState {
   contacts?: Contacts,
   user?: object,
   activeUserId?: string | null
}
```

Comment: Hello @s.hesam, if I do this I get the following error in the *Sidebar* component: *"TS2322: Type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Contacts[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Contacts[]'."* This error is present on *let contactsValues: Array<Contacts> = contacts && Object.values(contacts);*.